# Select a section from a file r studio

Tags: r

Select a section from a file,
I want to get the whole section from the word I choose to the beginning of the next word section.

```
data <- c("Ran hi i man and bla bla"
         ,"and want bla bla thxx",
         "Dan hello i want to fly",
         "thxx all",
         "David hello i want to fly",
         "thxx all",
         "Yanis hello i want to fly",
         "thxx all")

ran <- data[str_detect(str_to_lower(data),"ran")]
David <- data[str_detect(str_to_lower(data),"David")]
Yanis <- data[str_detect(str_to_lower(data),"Yanis")]
Dan <- data[str_detect(str_to_lower(data),"Dan")]
```

give me only the row, i want all the text until the next name "dan".

get....
ran=Ran hi i man and bla bla

want get
ran = Ran hi i man and bla bla
and want bla bla thxx

Sorry about the English thxx

**update:**

i write this its work, but i want A short way is with more names, it is a mess and a lot of work.
x <- c("ran","dan","yanis","david")
have way do this from ran to x ?
sub(".*ran *(.*?) *stopnewname.*", "\1", data2222)

```
data <- tolower(data)
data <- str_c(data,collapse = " ")
data2222 <- str_replace_all(data, c("dan" = "stopnewname", "yanis" = "stopnewname", "david" = "stopnewname"))
print(c("ran",sub(".*ran *(.*?) *stopnewname.*", "\\1", data2222)))
data2222 <- str_replace_all(data, c("ran" = "stopnewname", "yanis" = "stopnewname", "david" = "stopnewname"))
print(c("dan",sub(".*dan *(.*?) *stopnewname.*", "\\1", data2222)))
data2222 <- str_replace_all(data, c("ran" = "stopnewname", "dan" = "stopnewname", "david" = "stopnewname"))
print(c("yanis",sub(".*yanis *(.*?) *stopnewname.*", "\\1", data2222)))
data2222 <- str_replace_all(data, c("ran" = "stopnewname", "dan" = "stopnewname", "yanis" = "stopnewname"))
print(c("david",sub(".*david *(.*?) *stopnewname.*", "\\1", data2222)))
```

Comment: sub(".*ran *(.*?) *dan.*", "\\1", data) i can amke here multi ? *ran* to "dan,yanis,david" ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. What is `SASASASA` ? If `data` is your input what output are you looking for?

Comment: this code now give me ouput : in row have  "ran" give the all row but i want he give me all from ran to next name (dan,yanis,david)

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output? If I run `data` shared I get an error `Error: unexpected symbol in "David hello"`

Comment: i get data like i fix here i import him from txt file

Comment: data <- readLines("C:/Users/mmmm/data.txt")

Comment: ````data <- tolower(data)
data <- str_c(data,collapse = " ")
sub(".*ran *(.*?) *dan.*", "\\1", data)```     i try this but i want from ran to dan or yanis or david

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, once you have collapsed your text:

```
data <- "ran hi i man and bla bla and want bla bla thxx dan hello i want to fly thxx all david hello i want to fly thxx all yanis hello i want to fly thxx all"
```

You want to select everything between "string1" (e.g. "ran") and "string2" (e.g. "dan"). So you can use a regular expression:

```
"string1(.*)string2"
```

Here, `.` means any character, `*` means any number of times.

You want "string1" to be "ran", and "string2" to be either "dan" or "yanis" or "david". So you can use "|" to mean OR.

```
"ran(.*)(dan|yanis|david)"
```

You can use the function `str_match()` to extract what is in the parentheses `(.*)`

```
str_match(data, "ran(.*)(dan|yanis|david)")
```

But you will have a problem: `str_match()` will find the *longest* string between "ran" and "yanis", I think you want the *shortest* between "ran" and "dan". You can add a `?` after `.*` to say that.

```
str_match(data, "ran(.*?)(dan|yanis|david)")
#     [,1]                                                
# [1,] "ran hi i man and bla bla and want bla bla thxx dan"
#     [,2]                                          
# [1,] " hi i man and bla bla and want bla bla thxx "
#     [,3] 
# [1,] "dan"
```

And you can select only the result:

```
str_match(data, "ran(.*?)(dan|yanis|david)")[[2]]
# [1] " hi i man and bla bla and want bla bla thxx "
```